# batch rename files keeping substring and adding mm and yy

Tags: date, batch-file, substring, rename

I have a series of files that have long filenames. For each filename that contains a hyphen I would like to keep the substring in position 6-8, append the **_FM07_FY14.prn**  to the name and ignore the rest of the original filename.  The new extension is now .prn.  The two digits 07 stands for the month and 14 is the year.  The month and year can be found from the "date created" property. Will appreciate it if you can show me how to automatically capture this mm and yy from the date created.  Hardcoding this part is okay too since I can sort files by created dates and put them in separate folders.

For example

aaaaaD07.dfdd-1234.A.b.1233 new filename will be **D07**_FM01_FY14.prn

bbcbaA30dls-d343.a.123d new filename will be **A30**_FM01_FY14.prn

cdq0dG12ir3-438d.dfd.txt new filename will be **G12**_FM01_FY14.prn

This is the .bat file I come up with after reading many posts on here, and I don't know how to extract the mm and yy so I hard code it.  I am not familiar with Powershell.  I can only handle a .bat or .cmd file and run it at the command prompt.  Any and all help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL


for %%F in (*.*) do (
 SET "name=%%a"  
 set "var=_FM01_FY14.prn"

 ren *-*  "%name:~6,8%var%"
)

*endlocal*
```

Comment: If any help is appreciated, I would not go this route, but use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/), use the multi-rename tool (CTRL-M) and the following rename string: [N6-8]_FM[=tc.creationdate.M]_FY[=tc.creationdate.M]

Comment: Are you sure you want the **creation** date, and not the **last-update** date?

Comment: Hi Magoo, either date will work because these files won't be updated until the extension and names are changed. It's cool to know the parameter of the last-update date too, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\one"
PUSHD %sourcedir%
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "*" '
 ) DO (
 SET name=%%a
 SET fdate=%%~ta
 ECHO(REN "%%a" "!name:~5,3!_FM!fdate:~3,2!_FY!fdate:~8,2!.prn"
)
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The format that I use for date is `dd/mm/yyyy` If yours is different, then you'll need to change the offset in the `!fdate:~m,2!` phrases. The value of `m` is the offset into the date string from the first character (the second parameter is the number of characters to select.)

The required REN commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(REN` to `REN` to actually rename the files.